# In AutoHotKey , how would I automatically type in two consecutive apostrophes when I click two locations?

Tags: autohotkey

I've downloaded AutoHotKey and want to use it to make it easier to insert data into a database.

I'd like to be able to press a hotkey, then autohotkey prints an `'`  at wherever I am, waits a second(so I can reposition my cursor) , and then prints another `'` wherever the new cursor location is.'

So far , I have this:

```
#!z::
'
Sleep, 1000  ; 1 second
'
```

but this gives me an error at the `'` (apostrophe symbol)

any help appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

' by itself does nothing; use [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) for sending characters to active window.

```
#!z::
    Send, {'}
    Sleep, 1000  ; 1 second
    Send, {'}
return
```

Comment: To improve upon this, you could also do `KeyWait, LButton, D` instead of the Sleep line.  This will do the second send after you click.

Comment: @Elliot, Great suggestion, more in line with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that I use:

When I need to type a variable that starts and ends with a <kbd>%</kbd> sign, I do the following: type <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> twice, the cursor is then brought back right in between the two percent signs, so I can type (or paste) the variable name.

Here is the code:

```
:?*:%%::%%{Left}
```

You could do the same for <kbd>'</kbd>:

```
:?*:''::''{Left}
```

B.t.w. I do the same for the code that shows the keys in this article.

```
:?*:kb\::<kbd></kbd>{left 6}
```

When I write <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, this will write the two tags first and then jump right to the place where you put in the key name.